# check user signed in group signature

Tags: signature

I have $N$ users, all of them creating a group digital signature. Also I have user $A$. How can I check if user a signed or not signet in this signature? Is it possible ? Are there other methods how I can check if user $A$ is one of the group $N$?

Comment: Is it a group signature scheme or ring scheme? Would you refer to your definition?

Comment: I don't know what is better the group of ring signature, and since a ring signature is a type of group signature I wrote group signature, but the problem is how I can check if the user is signed or not, I need to understand algorithm of checking, and what is better use for it, may be signature is not a good technology for it.

Comment: What exactly is "user is signed in a signature" according to your definition? Or, could you see something anything that would fit your ideas at Bellare' paper at http://kodu.ut.ee/~lipmaa/crypto/link/signature/group.php ?

Comment: Let say we have three users A, B, C all of them let say sign a paper (create a signature). Now I need a method, witch will say if a user sign this document or not.

Comment: I'd suggest to omit "group" from the question. What is your research done already?

Comment: well as I tried different types of signatures schemes, also I thinking about making encryption with multiple keys. And I look at algorithms of breaking hash if you have a small part of it. Well I don't find a lot of info and run out of ideas, what why I wrote here. I thinking that signature is not what the best for that kind of problem

Comment: It looks straightforward to check whether signature verification equation holds for specific user public key. What is your favorite handbook on cryptography and signatures?

Comment: well i don't have a favorite book, but I found very interesting lectures here - [link] (http://cyberleninka.ru/search#q=%40%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80+%22%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD+%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9+%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%22&page=1)

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you mean is a *multi-signature*.  A *group or ring signature* usually refers to an anonymous signature that can be produced by any member of a certain group.  Group signature scheme offers the additional feature that anonymity can be revoked by some group authority.

Comment: @user94293 yes it what I need, I need that whole group (let say A B and C) sign, and revoke anonymity to whole group to understand if the user (C) sign it.

Comment: See e.g. the scheme by Bellare and Neven; [CT-RSA 2007](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F11967668_10)